# Actualizar registro a traves de su relacion

Tags: laravel

tengo 2 modelos: Post y References con una relacion post hasMany Reference
La tabla references contiene:
**id
url
post_id**

La peculiaridad es que el sistema esta diseñado para que un post pueda tener entre 1 y max 3 referencias, por lo que el request vendra siendo un array de 1 hasta 3 valores.

Modelo Post

```
public function references()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reference::class);
    }
```

Necesito actualizar los registros de las references que vienen desde un form request.

```
 $post->references()->update($request['reference']);
```

Pero me da error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'
```

Como seria la forma correcta de hacerlo? Estoy con laravel 8
Gracias

Comment: El valor que necesitas actualizar es unicamente de *references* o necesitas actualizar ese valor con base en algo relacionado con *post*?

Comment: Solamente necesito actualizar la tabla references, pero se me olvido mencionar que los posts pueden tener minimo 1 o maximo 3 referencias. Por lo que el request['references] es un array que en ocasiones viene con 1 registro o maximo 3. Edito la pregunta